# Calculate percentage of zeros and ones in my vector?

Tags: matlab, vector, percentage, transition

I've already have my vector and number of  zeros and ones with this code:

```
u=[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
transitions=(find(u~=[u(2:end), u(end)+1]));
value=u(transitions)
transitions(2:end)=transitions(2:end)-transitions(1:end-1)
```

i get this

```
 value =

 1     0     1     0     1     0


 transitions =

 5     3     2     7     5     3
```

Now, please if someone could help me and explain how I can get percentage of ones and percentage of zeros in my vector (all together, and by each value).
Thank You very much.

Comment: You might want to add the Matlab tag.

Comment: Also, what does `all together, and by each value)` mean? You want the percentage for each index in `transitions`?

Comment: yes that is correct, i found how to calculate total percentage of zeros and ones, and now i need percentage for each index in transitions.

Comment: what about mean(u==1) or even just mean(u) as the proportion of ones in your binary vector?

Comment: that is for total percentage. but i need percentage of each value in 'transitions' vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly it is very simple:

```
p1=sum(u)./numel(u); % is the percentage of ones
p2=1-p1;             % is the percentage of zeros
```

Matlab has even this spesific function called tabulate that creates a frequency table just for that:

```
tabulate(u)

Value    Count   Percent
      0       13     52.00%
      1       12     48.00%
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just psuedocode so it'll need to be translated, but here's a potential solution:

```
total = 0;
total_ones = 0;
total_zeroes = 0;

for(i=0; i<transitions.length; i++){
    total += transitions[i];
    if(value[i] == 0)
        total_zeroes += transitions[i];
    else
        total_ones += transitions[i];
}

print("Percent Zeroes: " + (total_zeroes/total)*100);
print("Percent Ones: " + (total_ones/total)*100);

#To print each group's percent it'd be along the lines of the following:
for(i=0; i<transitions.length; i++){
    print("Percent of total comprised of this group: " + (transitions[i]/total)*100)
}
```

Comment: maybe easier solution                                                     u=[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
pctg_1 = sum(u)/size(u,2) * 100         % Percentage of ‘1’
pctg_0 = 100 - pctg_1                   % Percentage of ‘0’
produces:

pctg_1 =
      48.0000
pctg_0 =
      52.0000